# Which is faster: input[type="checkbox"] or :checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

So which should I use to select elements? I'm using checkbox as just an example, this question refers to all form elements.

Actually while we are at it, which of these are faster:

```
li:first
```

or

```
li:eq(0)
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/):

Although, semantically:

> `$(':checkbox')` is equivalent to `$('[type=checkbox]')`

practically speaking:

> Because `:checkbox` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using `:checkbox` cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()`
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   `[type="checkbox"]` instead.

**Always read the documentation.** It will make your life easier, and ours.

Comment: Downvoting a verbatim quote from the official documentation. Very nice.

Comment: @karim79: And in any other browser that arbitrarily one day decides to join that club, without any legal obligation to inform _you_ about it first. (Also, you appear to have missed the phrase "in modern browsers".)

Comment: @karim79: It's called due diligence. Yes, it is still the correct answer. Are hares faster than snails? "Oh well what if the hare had all its legs chopped off by a rampant chainsaw" "Seriously? Shut up" <-- this is us. :) [I will not be responding to any more trollbait comments on this question.]

Comment: @karim79: Break your addiction to proprietary selectors today, and enjoy future-proofed code. You don't want to be tied to Sizzle forever, do you? ;o)

Comment: Fine, fine. You win. I'll be using `[type="checkbox"]` from now on. Have removed my "trollbaiting" comments (and down-vote, for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

You can see the performance difference for yourself in [this testcase](http://jsperf.com/accessing-checkboxes).

In the browsers tested so far, `:checkbox` is a lot slower.

For the second part of your question: using `:first` or `:eq(0)` [doesn't seem to make much difference](http://jsperf.com/accessing-listitems).

Comment: To make the test fair, I think you'd really need to add the element selector `input:checkbox` like you did for `input[type="checkbox"]`. That closes the gap quite a bit in Chrome. http://jsperf.com/accessing-checkboxes/2

Comment: ...of course your test does reflect what the question specified in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers are implemented differently.  It will be impossible to choose an answer that is true for all of them.  Different sized pages might even change the answer.  You need to test your code for performance problems, and fix the ones you find.  It's extremely unlikely that the difference between these simple selectors will be a problem.

Comment: +1 Dunno why that got a minus, it's sound advice. If performance is really an issue, don't use jQuery. It's selectors can be 10 to 100 times slower than equivalent DOM methods.